# in R, how to make subcolumns (dataframes in dataframes) to be in the same column level?

Tags: r, dataframe, flatten

in R, how to make subcolumns (dataframes in dataframes) to be in the same column level?

for example:
The attributes of my dataframe are these:
As you can see, in order to find column x0 i must use df$z$x0, or x2 df$v$x2. so how can I can "flat" the columns of this dataframe to be able to call x0 or x2 directly e.g. df$x0, df$x2? 
I knwo that i can take every column and assign it again to a new dataframe. Although, I hope that a function exists to do that directly.

```
 $ perc0: num  14.4 16.9 31.1 37.7
 $ z    :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ x0: Factor w/ 254 levels "Boy.Numbercigs.0",..: 192 193 239 240
 $ v    :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ GENDER: Factor w/ 2 levels "Boy","Girl": 1 2 1 2
  ..$ X2    : Factor w/ 1 level "EDUCATION": 1 1 1 1
  ..$ X3    : Factor w/ 2 levels "High School",..: 1 1 2 2
```

the R output gives that dataframe by writing e.g. df:

```
  perc0                         x0 v.GENDER      v.X2        v.X3
1 14.39  Boy.EDUCATION.High School      Boy EDUCATION High School
2 16.86 Girl.EDUCATION.High School     Girl EDUCATION High School
3 31.06    Boy.EDUCATION.Secondary      Boy EDUCATION   Secondary
4 37.69   Girl.EDUCATION.Secondary     Girl EDUCATION   Secondary
```

Comment: Is there a command, to directly giving the R command of the construction of a given dataframe? e.g. Give_construction_command_for_df(df) df<-c(........), column names=c(.........) ?

Comment: maybe there is a more efficient way but this works `out_df <- NULL;
lapply(df, function(x) out_df <<- cbind(out_df, x))`